# converted json column in pandas data frame into nested json output

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have a json column in a dataframe df, where i am trying to convert it into a nested json and save it as a txt file for clients:

dataframe df

```
"json":{"0":{"status":"Active","task_name":"transientAlertf9b8b69eb4b84bd597b3983566ffc538","schedule":"","owner":"","task_type":"FraudIncremental","created_date":"Tue, 08 Jan 2019 00:34:43 GMT","parameters":{"program":"abc","subject":"abc ","days_back":1,"last_run_status":"OK"},"category":"Alert","permission":"private","messaging_channels":[{"channel_type":"email","cc":"","recipients":[""],"bcc":""}],"tags":"Fraud"}}}
```

into a nested json and save into txt

```
    {
  "created_date": "Tue, 08 Jan 2019 00:34:43 GMT",
  "schedule": "",
  "parameters": {
    "last_run_status": "OK",
    "subject": "abc ",
    "days_back": 1,
    "program": "abc"
  },
  "status": "Active",
  "permission": "private",
  "task_type": "abc",
  "tags": "Fraud",
  "messaging_channels": [
    {
      "bcc": "",
      "cc": "",
      "channel_type": "email",
      "recipients": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "task_name": "transientAlertf9b8b69eb4b84bd597b3983566ffc538",
  "category": "Alert",
  "owner": ""
}
```

ANy thoughts? Thanks.

I have checked a few posts and they are not quite the same

[Pandas DataFrame to Nested JSON Without Changing Data Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183789/pandas-dataframe-to-nested-json-without-changing-data-structure)

[DataFrame to nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143783/dataframe-to-nested-json)

[Convert a Pandas Dataframe into a nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092512/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-into-a-nested-json)

[Convert Pandas Dataframe to nested JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40470954/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-nested-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the df you gave as an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"json":{"0":{"status":"Active","task_name":"transientAlertf9b8b69eb4b84bd597b3983566ffc538","schedule":"","owner":"","task_type":"FraudIncremental","created_date":"Tue, 08 Jan 2019 00:34:43 GMT","parameters":{"program":"abc","subject":"abc ","days_back":1,"last_run_status":"OK"},"category":"Alert","permission":"private","messaging_channels":[{"channel_type":"email","cc":"","recipients":[""],"bcc":""}],"tags":"Fraud"}}})
df

    json
0   {'status': 'Active', 'task_name': 'transientAl...
```

Running the below code converts the contents of all rows in the `json` column to json entries and saves them all to a text file where they appear nicely formatted:

```
import json

json_data = df['json'].to_json(orient='index')
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json.loads(json_data), outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
```

This is how `data.txt` appears when opened in notepad:

```
{
  "0": {
    "category": "Alert",
    "created_date": "Tue, 08 Jan 2019 00:34:43 GMT",
    "messaging_channels": [
      {
        "bcc": "",
        "cc": "",
        "channel_type": "email",
        "recipients": [
          ""
        ]
      }
    ],
    "owner": "",
    "parameters": {
      "days_back": 1,
      "last_run_status": "OK",
      "program": "abc",
      "subject": "abc "
    },
    "permission": "private",
    "schedule": "",
    "status": "Active",
    "tags": "Fraud",
    "task_name": "transientAlertf9b8b69eb4b84bd597b3983566ffc538",
    "task_type": "FraudIncremental"
  }
}
```