# How to convert nested JSON data from a URL into a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, url

```
import json
import pandas
import requests
```

[Convert to Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54641676/converted-json-column-in-pandas-data-frame-into-nested-json-output)

I know what you're going to say, this has been asked before. But ive gone through a number of posts already and they all require importing the json file into the code already.
So with this code I've been trying to import the json data through a URL, so there is no need to save any files before hand.

Is it even possible?
Please help.

Comment: There is a way to achieve json to csv transformation through pandas - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

Answer (score 1):

Pandas `json_normalize` can do just that.  Here is an example for which you will have to modify to meet your specific needs:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(packages_json, record_path='results')
```

(I omitted the output from the DF because is it unwieldy)

Comment: wow thank you, its workin! right now not all the headers (rows and columns) are being shown, but i assume there is a way to adjust that

Comment: @Craig Play around with the `meta` parameter to access more fields.